# Counting words in files - follow-up

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading, file

I have made a non-threaded version of counting words. The result was unexpected the non-threaded version was faster than threaded-parallel version.

Non-threaded version:

```
//
// program name: WordCounter
//
// usage: C:\>WordCounter.exe test.txt test1.txt 
//
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <exception>

#include "Profiler.h"

using Words = std::unordered_map < std::string, std::size_t >;

Words loadFromFile(const std::string& fileName)
{
    std::ifstream file(fileName);

    if (!file)
    {
        throw "Can't open the file " + fileName;
    }

    Words words;

    for (std::string word; file >> word;)
    {
        ++words[word];
    }

    return words;
}

template<typename T>
void showResult(T begin, T end)
{
    std::vector<T> words;

    words.reserve(std::distance(begin, end));

    for (auto i = begin; i != end; ++i)
    {
        words.push_back(i);
    }

    std::sort(words.begin(), words.end(),
        [](const T& it1, const T& it2)
    {
        return it1->second > it2->second;
    });

    int x = 0;

    for (const auto& i : words)
    {
        if (x++ == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "\nThe most repeated element is: " << i->first << "\n\n";

            std::cout << " Word\tRepeated Times";

            std::cout << '\n' << std::setfill('-') << std::setw(28) << '\n';
        }

        std::printf(" %-10s%5d\n", i->first.c_str(), i->second);
    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    profiler.begin("test");

    std::vector<Words> resources;

    resources.reserve(argc - 1);

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        resources.push_back(loadFromFile(argv[i]));
    }

    Words words;

    for (auto& i : resources)
    {
        Words result = i;

        for (auto& j : result)
        {
            words[j.first] += j.second;
        }
    }

    showResult(words.begin(), words.end());

    profiler.end("test");

    std::cout << '\n' << profiler.data("test") << " seconds\n";
}
```

Threaded-parallel version:

```
//
// program name: WordCounter
//
// usage: C:\>WordCounter.exe test.txt test1.txt 
//
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <exception>

#include "Profiler.h"

using Words = std::unordered_map < std::string, std::size_t >;

Words loadFromFile(const std::string& fileName)
{
    std::ifstream file(fileName);

    if (!file)
    {
        throw "Can't open the file " + fileName;
    }

    Words words;

    for (std::string word; file >> word;)
    {
        ++words[word];
    }

    return words;
}

template<typename T>
void showResult(T begin, T end)
{
    std::vector<T> words;

    words.reserve(std::distance(begin, end));

    for (auto i = begin; i != end; ++i)
    {
        words.push_back(i);
    }

    std::sort(words.begin(), words.end(),
        [](const T& it1, const T& it2)
    {
        return it1->second > it2->second;
    });

    int x = 0;

    for (const auto& i : words)
    {
        if (x++ == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "\nThe first most repeated element is: " << i->first << "\n\n";

            std::cout << " Word\tRepeated Times";

            std::cout << '\n' << std::setfill('-') << std::setw(28) << '\n';
        }

        std::printf(" %-10s%5d\n", i->first.c_str(), i->second);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    profiler.begin("test");

    std::vector<std::future<Words>> resources;

    resources.reserve(argc - 1);

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        resources.push_back(std::async(loadFromFile, argv[i]));
    }

    Words words;

    for (auto& i : resources)
    {
        Words results;

        try
        {
            results = i.get();
        }
        catch (std::exception &err)
        {
            std::cerr << "ERROR: " << err.what() << '\n';
        }
        catch (std::string &err)
        {
            std::cerr << "ERROR: " << err << '\n';
        }

        for (const auto& j : results)
        {
            words[j.first] += j.second;
        }
    }

    showResult(words.begin(), words.end());

    profiler.end("test");

    std::cout << '\n' << profiler.data("test") << " seconds\n";
}
```

Profiler header file:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef PROFILER_H
#define PROFILER_H

#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <chrono>

class Profiler
{
public:

    struct TimeData
    {
        TimeData() = default;
        std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, end;
        std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds;
    };

    void begin(const std::string& name)
    {
        const auto& it = mData.find(name);

        if (it != mData.end())
        {
            TimeData& time = it->second;

            time.start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        }
        else
        {
            TimeData time;

            time.start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

            mData[name] = time;
        }

    }

    void end(const std::string& name)
    {
        const auto& it = mData.find(name);

        if (it != mData.end())
        {
            TimeData& time = it->second;

            time.end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

            time.elapsed_seconds = time.end - time.start;
        }
    }

    double data(const std::string& name)const
    {
        const auto& it = mData.find(name);

        if (it != mData.end())
            return it->second.elapsed_seconds.count();

        return 0;
    }

    std::map<std::string, TimeData> mData;

}profiler;

#endif // PROFILER_H
```

Resource files:

test.txt

> ```
> File system is huge subject need more work out. file is plain text file
> This is some junk words. simple program for words counting in text file. 1 2 3
> 2 2 2 2
> @ % & ^ *
> all so good
> this test text file
> ```

test1.txt

> file system second file, test multiple files

Output for non-threaded version:

> ```
> The most repeated element is: 2
>
>  Word   Repeated Times
> ---------------------------
>  2             5
>  file          4
>  text          3
>  is            3
>  system        2
>  test          2
>  File          1
>  1             1
>  need          1
>  huge          1
>  subject       1
>  %             1
>  more          1
>  work          1
>  plain         1
>  This          1
>  some          1
>  program       1
>  junk          1
>  words.        1
>  simple        1
>  files         1
>  for           1
>  words         1
>  counting      1
>  in            1
>  so            1
>  file.         1
>  3             1
>  @             1
>  &             1
>  this          1
>  ^             1
>  file,         1
>  *             1
>  all           1
>  good          1
>  out.          1
>  second        1
>  mulitiple     1
>
> 0.0646741 seconds
> ```

Output for threaded version:

> ```
> The first most repeated element is: 2
>
>  Word   Repeated Times
> ---------------------------
>  2             5
>  file          4
>  is            3
>  text          3
>  system        2
>  test          2
>  out.          1
>  1             1
>  need          1
>  huge          1
>  subject       1
>  work          1
>  more          1
>  %             1
>  plain         1
>  This          1
>  some          1
>  junk          1
>  program       1
>  words.        1
>  simple        1
>  files         1
>  for           1
>  words         1
>  counting      1
>  in            1
>  file.         1
>  so            1
>  3             1
>  @             1
>  &             1
>  ^             1
>  this          1
>  file,         1
>  *             1
>  all           1
>  good          1
>  File          1
>  second        1
>  mulitiple     1
>
> 0.0776089 seconds
> ```

Comment: You could use [`<chrono>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) to replace the Windows-specific code.

Comment: @glampert .. thanks it's even better. i updated the code

Comment: To ignore punctuation automatically: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6154217/14065

Comment: Why would you expect the threaded version to be faster. This is inherently a serial task (read a stream: Serial), (write a stream: serial). The only non serial task is sort and you have way to little data to make a parallel sort worth while.

Comment: @LokiAstari ... there is no particular reason. it's just common speaking we get used to hear. i  agree and i believe the locale part of the streams need further study. i just had one year since i start learning C++ i have a lot to learn. i'm just at first step i have long way ahead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exceptions should be used in exceptional cases. If you had a long list of files I wouldn't really see it as an exceptional case that a file name was wrong or could not be opened. The function caller still might want data from other files, and when possible its good to avoid using `try` / `catch`.

Instead I would opt for a pass by reference and a return status. The pass by reference could then work on the same map every time to avoid the unnecessary copying of map elements.

```
bool loadFromFile(const std::string& fileName, Words& words)
{
    std::ifstream file(fileName);
    if (!file)
    {
        return false;
    }
    for (std::string word; file >> word;)
    {
        ++words[word];
    }
    return true;
}
```

I decided to use a `bool` because there are only two events that terminate the function; open file error, and a successful read. If you have more than two types of return events, use an integer or better yet use an enumeration!

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    profiler.begin("test");
    // no need for resources variable
    Words words; 
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        if(!loadFromFile(argv[i], words))
        {
            std::cerr << "Can't open the file " << argv[i] << std::endl;
            // Decide to error and kill the program here if need be.
        }
    }
    showResult(words.begin(), words.end());

    profiler.end("test");
    std::cout << '\n' << profiler.data("test") << " seconds\n";
}
```

Comment: I have always hated the phrase: `Exceptions should be used in exceptional cases.` It has no meaning. A better phrase: `Exceptions should be used when an error can not corrected locally` You can optimally be more specific with `and requires control to passed up the call hierarchy to parent that can not be determined at compile time that can correct the error.`

Comment: @LokiAstari I always presumed your definition there to be the meaning behind the phrase :p