# Counting words in files - follow-up 2

Tags: c++, c++11, file, template, template-meta-programming

Previous question:

[Counting words in files - follow-up](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/73452/counting-words-in-files-follow-up)

I have fixed punctuation problems in my previous code by using template, because it is easy to understand and my focus on template mechanism. The same applies for optimizing code.

**Source code**

```
//
//program name: WordCounter
//
//usage: C:\>WordCounter.exe test.txt test1.txt 
//

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <exception>

template<bool...>
struct BoolSequence
{
};

template<std::make_unsigned<char>::type...>
struct CharSequence
{
};

template<typename T, std::make_unsigned<char>::type C>
struct Contains;

template<std::make_unsigned<char>::type First, std::make_unsigned<char>::type... Cs, std::make_unsigned<char>::type Match>
struct Contains<CharSequence<First, Cs...>, Match>  
    : Contains<CharSequence<Cs...>, Match>
{
};

template<std::make_unsigned<char>::type First, std::make_unsigned<char>::type... Cs>
struct Contains<CharSequence<First, Cs...>, First>
    : std::true_type
{
};

template<std::make_unsigned<char>::type Match>
struct Contains<CharSequence<>, Match>
    : std::false_type
{
};

template<std::make_unsigned<int>::type  I, typename T, typename U>
struct MakeSequence;

template<std::make_unsigned<int>::type I, bool... Bs, typename U>
struct MakeSequence<I, BoolSequence<Bs...>, U>
    : MakeSequence<I - 1, BoolSequence<Contains<U, I - 1>::value, Bs...>, U>
{
};

template<bool... Bs, typename U>
struct MakeSequence<0, BoolSequence<Bs...>, U>
{
    using Type = BoolSequence<Bs...>;
};

template<typename T>
struct BoolASCIITable;

template<bool... Bs>
struct BoolASCIITable<BoolSequence<Bs...>>
{
    bool operator()(const int c) const
    {
        static const bool table[] = { Bs... };
        return table[c];
    }
    using argument_type = char;
};

using Delims = CharSequence<'.', ','>;
using Table = BoolASCIITable<typename MakeSequence<256, BoolSequence<>, Delims>::Type>;
using Words = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::size_t>;

template<typename T>
std::pair<T, T> getToken(T begin, T end)
{
    begin = find_if(begin, end, std::not1(Table{}));
    auto second = find_if(begin, end, Table{});
    return std::make_pair(begin, second);
}


bool loadFromFile(const std::string& fileName, Words& words)
{
    std::ifstream file(fileName);

    if (!file)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (std::string word; file >> word;)
    {
        auto s = getToken(word.begin(), word.end());
        ++words[std::string(s.first, s.second)];
    }

    return true;
}

template<typename T>
void showResult(const T& begin, const T& end)
{
    std::vector<T> words;

    words.reserve(std::distance(begin, end));

    for (auto i = begin; i != end; ++i)
    {
        words.push_back(i);
    }

    std::sort(words.begin(), words.end(),
        [&](const T& it1, const T& it2)
    {
        return it1->second > it2->second;
    });

    int x = 0;

    for (const auto& i : words)
    {
        if (x++ == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "\nThe most repeated element is: " << i->first << "\n\n";

            std::cout << " Word\tRepeated Times";

            std::cout << '\n' << std::setfill('-') << std::setw(23) << '\n';
        }
        std::cout << ' ' << std::setfill(' ')
            << std::setw(10) << std::left << i->first
            << std::setw(6) << std::internal << i->second << '\n';
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Words words;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        if (!loadFromFile(argv[i], words))
        {
            std::cerr << "Can't open the file " << argv[i] << '\n';
        }
    }

    showResult(words.begin(), words.end());
}
```

**Resource files**

test.txt

> ```
> File system is huge subject need more work out. file is plain text file
> This is some junk words. simple program for words counting in text file. 1 2 3
> 2 2 2 2
> @ % & ^ *
> all so good
> this test text file
> ```

test1.txt

> `file system second file, test multiple files`

Output:

> ```
> The most repeated element is: file
>
>  Word   Repeated Times
> ----------------------
>  file           6
>  2              5
>  is             3
>  text           3
>  system         2
>  words          2
>  test           2
>  need           1
>  huge           1
>  @              1
>  out            1
>  subject        1
>  %              1
>  more           1
>  work           1
>  plain          1
>  This           1
>  some           1
>  program        1
>  junk           1
>  File           1
>  simple         1
>  files          1
>  for            1
>  counting       1
>  in             1
>  3              1
>  &              1
>  multiple       1
>  this           1
>  ^              1
>  *              1
>  all            1
>  so             1
>  good           1
>  1              1
>  second         1
> ```

Comment: Please include a brief summary of the problem being solved, rather than requiring us to follow a link to find out.  Thanks!