# Counting words in files - follow-up-3

Tags: c++, c++11, file

Previous question:

[Counting words in files - follow-up 2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/73540/counting-words-in-files-follow-up-2)

For simplifying the code, I have implemented `std::regex` rather than templates.

How can I improve this code further?

```
//
//program name: WordCounter
//
//usage: C:\>WordCounter.exe test.txt test1.txt 
//
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <regex>

using Words = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::size_t>;

template<typename T>
std::string getToken(T begin, T end, std::regex e = std::regex{ R"([^.,\n\r]+)" })
{
    std::smatch match{};

    std::string result{};

    if (std::regex_search(begin, end, match, e))
    {
        result.append(match.str());
    }

    return result;
}

bool loadFromFile(const std::string& fileName, Words& words)
{
    std::ifstream file(fileName);

    if (!file)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (std::string word; file >> word;)
    {
        ++words[getToken(word.cbegin(), word.cend())];
    }

    return true;
}

template<typename T>
void showResult(const T& begin, const T& end)
{
    std::vector<T> words;

    words.reserve(std::distance(begin, end));

    for (auto i = begin; i != end; ++i)
    {
        words.push_back(i);
    }

    std::sort(words.begin(), words.end(),
        [&](const T& it1, const T& it2)
    {
        return it1->second > it2->second;
    });

    int x = 0;

    for (const auto& i : words)
    {
        if (x++ == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "\nThe most repeated element is: " << i->first << "\n\n";

            std::cout << " Word\tRepeated Times";

            std::cout << '\n' << std::setfill('-') << std::setw(23) << '\n';
        }

        std::cout << ' ' << std::setfill(' ')
            << std::setw(10) << std::left << i->first
            << std::setw(6) << std::internal << i->second << '\n';
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Words words;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        if (!loadFromFile(argv[i], words))
        {
            std::cerr << "Can't open the file " << argv[i] << '\n';
        }
    }

    showResult(words.begin(), words.end());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overall, this looks pretty nice. There are few minor things that can be improved though, about this part:

> ```
> int x = 0;
>
> for (const auto& i : words)
> {
>     if (x++ == 0)
>     {
>         std::cout << "\nThe most repeated element is: " << i->first << "\n\n";
>
>         std::cout << " Word\tRepeated Times";
>
>         std::cout << '\n' << std::setfill('-') << std::setw(23) << '\n';
>     }
>
>     // ...
> }
> ```

`i` is customary for loop variables that are simple counters.
In this case it is a *word* (well, sort of), 
so it would be better to name it as such.

The variable `x` is a bit confusing:

- its name tells nothing of its purpose
- it's important for the first iteration of the loop
- ... but it keeps counting during all iterations

It would be clearer and better this way:

```
bool first = true;

for (const auto& word : words)
{
    if (first)
    {
        std::cout << "\nThe most repeated element is: " << word->first << "\n\n";

        std::cout << " Word\tRepeated Times";

        std::cout << '\n' << std::setfill('-') << std::setw(23) << '\n';

        first = false;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should include (actually exclude) more characters in your regex, like parentheses, question and exclamation marks or even change it to something like `(\w+)` to leave only letters in the match because `ifstream`s `file >> word` breaks on spaces.

Comment: thanks for answer. actually my txt file has only `,` `.` punctuations, so i need only these.

Comment: for whitespace i had content of file in `unordered_map`. it stores each word in it.